# 2d array information displayed in a table

Tags: python, arrays, datatable

The program should display the results in a tabular format, with each column representing a school and each row representing one of the donation amounts. Total and display each column and row.

First I have the schools and create the 2d array.

```
schools = ["Catholic Central","Holy Cross","John Paul II","Mother Teresa","Regina Mundi","St. Joseph","St. Mary","St. Thomas Aquinas"]
donations = [.25,.5,1,2]
collected = []

for row in range(0,len(schools)):
    collected.append([])

for row in range (0,len(schools)):
    for col in range (0,len(donations)):
      collected[row].append(0)
```

With the 2d array I created I want it to output something that looks like this:

```
Donations  Catholic Central Holy Cross John Paul II Mother Teresa Regina Mundi St. Joseph St. Mary St. Thomas Aquinas TOTAL
0.25       0.0              0.0        0.0          0.0           0.0          0.0        0.0      0.0                 0.0
0.50       0.0              0.0        0.0          0.0           0.0          0.0        0.0      0.0                 0.0
1.00       0.0              0.0        0.0          0.0           0.0          0.0        0.0      0.0                 0.0
2.00       0.0              0.0        0.0          0.0           0.0          0.0        0.0      0.0                 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty table is a very useful (external) module you could use. More details are found here:
https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/.
First you need to download it:

```
python -m pip install -U prettytable
```

After importing it:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
```

Then you create your rows and headers:

```
x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]
x.add_row(["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
```

Or:

```
x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]
x.add_rows(
    [
        ["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5],
        ["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4],
        ["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7],
        ["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5],
        ["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8],
        ["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9],
        ["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4],
    ]
)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```